# Superimpose 2 plots in matplotlib - empty plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a circle and a rectangle on the same graph with matplotlib.

Instead, I get an empty plot. What should I do?

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

plt.axes()
circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=0.75, fc='y')
plt.axis('scaled')
rectangle = plt.Rectangle((10, 10), 100, 100, fc='r')
plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly working. The only issue is

```
plt.axis('scaled')
```

Double check your axis limits - this line only works with normal plot objects, not patches, so if you remove this line you should see the rectangle (though you also **forgot to add the circle** in your pasted code), as long you you update the axis limits (I used `plt.axis([-1, 120, -1, 120])` below to achieve this).

A full working listing is:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

plt.axes()
circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=0.75, fc='y')
plt.gca().add_patch(circle)
rectangle = plt.Rectangle((10, 10), 100, 100, fc='r')
plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
plt.axis([-1, 120, -1, 120])
```

Alternatively, `plt.autoscale` also works to set the data limits as suggested by tom.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the axes limits. You can do this with `plt.autoscale()`, or `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim`. You also need to add the circle patch. Add these lines at the end of your script:

```
plt.gca().add_patch(circle)
plt.autoscale()
```

[image]